# Word for "visualising exactly what would have happened there"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

In movies, characters go to a crime scene or something like that, find clues and they visualize like seeing what exactly would have happened there. My knowledge allowed me to find words like visualization, envision, envisage etc but nothing seems to be close enough.

I am looking for a name for my game. Beautiful English words welcomed :)

Thanks.

Comment: Why do those words not seem close enough?

Comment: imagining what took place, recreating what took place. NOT envisaging. I suggest: Re-Create.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check ***reconstruction*** - the process of using available evidence to "reconstruct" in mind the series of events that *possibly* led to the incident under investigation.

Macmillan:

> **[reconstruction](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/reconstruction)** 
>   *NOUN*
>   **2** [COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE] a situation in which you try to form an idea of something that happened by connecting pieces of information:
>   *a reconstruction of the crime*

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be [postcognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocognition) (or retrocognition).

> "knowledge of a past event which could not have been learned or inferred by normal means." - Dale, L.A. & White, R.A. in *Handbook of Parapsychology*

Note that this is not a scientific reconstruction: it is a paranormal reconstruction - the ability to recreate past events through psychic phenomena.  (It is essentially the opposite of precognition - the ability to divine the future through paranormal means.)

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=postcognition) will show a lot of comic book/movie/RPG/speculative fiction/etc. uses of the term.

Comment: An anonymous downvote with no reason?

Answer (score -2):

Envisage would be the correct word to use or at least one possibility. Conceive, ruminate and speculate are other synonyms that may work.

The technical term for how this is often achieved in screenwriting and in filmmaking is via 'exposition' but I doubt that word works in quite the way you're looking for it to. Exposition is the technique of giving audiences background information. It's provides an explanation of necessary background information to the audience. Some films do this better than others.

Comment: envisage is imagine. If you go to a place like a crime seen and look at things, you are not envisaging. That's for sure. You are imaging what took place.

Comment: I'd say that when a detective looks at a crime scene he has no choice but to envisage on some level what transpired. The event is already passed so he has no choice but to imagine it as it occurred. The actual physical artifacts of the crime are in the present and he looks at those but uses them to envisage or imagine how the crime occurred.

Comment: Perhaps envisage is used to refer to things that have not happened? The following three are examples of all of which refer to something that has not happened. So 

1) All three envisage Assad staying in power—at least in the short term.

2) Does he envisage the possibility of a political stalemate in Iraq? 

3) He triumphed because he had the moral imagination to envisage a relationship beyond confrontation and war.

If so then yes, envisage would be incorrect. Thinking out loud here.

Comment: Sorry, crime SCENE, above, not seen. :) envisage in English is usually about a future. Not about an incident that occurred in the past.